# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DegreeToggle from './DegreeToggle';
import DayCard from './DayCard';
class WeekContainer extends Component {
state = {
fullData: [],
dailyData: [],
degreeType: "fahrenheit"
}
componentDidMount = () => {
const weatherURL =
`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=c1bab0c96843878b6348982015110ecc`

fetch(weatherURL)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
  const dailyData = data.list.filter(reading => reading.dt_txt.includes("18:00:00"))
  this.setState({
    fullData: data.list,
    dailyData: dailyData
  }, () => console.log(this.state))
})
}
formatDayCards = () => {
return this.state.dailyData.map((reading, index) => <DayCard reading={reading} key={index} />)
}
updateForecastDegree = event => {
this.setState({
  degreeType: event.target.value
}, () => console.log(this.state))
```

}
render() {
return (

5-Day Forecast.
New York, US

{this.formatDayCards()}


)
}
}
export default WeekContainer;

I am developing a react js application and I am getting the error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: So `data.list` is undefined. What debugging steps have you taken to check if you get a valid response back?

Comment: your `data` may be have incorrect value it seems `list` is not in` data`, can you `console.log`. As some time its inside `data.data.list` or depend on your API output  so please check it once

Comment: looking at the response - there is no `list` property in the resulting data - you're probably using the wrong API endpoint

Comment: in fact, no openweathermap API returns a `list` property in the result - have you read the documentation for openweathermap API recently (it changes all the time)

Comment: when I am doing console.log(data.list) I am getting this error :  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
localhost/:1 Access to fetch at 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=c1bab0c96843878b6348982015110ecc' from origin 'http://localhost:8001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.